# ProtocolUnknownError when executing wkhtmltopdf from PHP with header and footer?

Tags: php, shell, wkhtmltopdf

I have a strange problem with wkhtmltopdf executed from PHP. My PHP code looks like this:

```
<?php
  exec('wkhtmltopdf --header-html "http://example.com/pdf-header" 
     --footer_html "http://example.com/pdf-footer"
     /tmp/pdf.html /tmp/pdf.pdf');
?>
```

When I execute the same command from shell, it works perfectly. However, when I try to run it from PHP like mentioned above, the script runs until it time outs resulting in empty PDF file.

As I searched web, I tried to run it with `> /tmp/error_log.txt 1>&2` parameter and I found out when executed from PHP it returns error:

```
Exit with code 1 due to network error: ProtocolUnknownError
```

More interestingly, when I delete `--footer-html` and `--header-html` it works fine executed from PHP. But obviously the resulting PDF is missing header and footer.

Header and footer HTML doesn't have any external resource references. And I don't think it is network / DNS problem because from commandline from the same server it works fine.

I would be very glad for any hints and tips, because this is driving me crazy. Thanks in advance.

Comment: in my case I had a bad reference (Ms Outlook)  to an image < img src="cid:dealer_image_id" . So this error was really saying cant find the image

Comment: In my case it was also a missing image (which was supposed to be loaded from the local file system)

Answer (score 3):

If someone has the same problem I will post my workaround solution I have used. Instead of using http URL for footer and header I put the HTML into local tmp files and use them as footer and header. This worked for me, might work for someone else too and save some hours.

Answer (score 3):

It is an old thread, but in case someone else searches for this error: it might be helpful to try it is caused by a problem importing a local file (ex: ./image). If so, passing the `--enable-local-file-access` flag might help.