Need help converting HTML to PDF files
I need to convert html files from a products Help directory to pdf. I have tried this:
import glob
import pdfkit

config = pdfkit.configuration(wkhtmltopdf=bytes("C:\\Program Files\\wkhtmltopdf\\bin\\wkhtmltopdf.exe", 'utf8'))

data = 'C:\\Users\\Me\\HTML2PDF\\Help\\*.html'

for name in glob.glob(data):
    print(name)
    pdfkit.from_file(name, name.pdf, configuration=config)

And this is the error I get:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\david.hyer\HTML2PDF4JoeBuc\Converter.py", line 14, in <module>
    pdfkit.from_file(name, name.pdf,configuration=config)
                           ^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'pdf'

What are my mistakes?

because the name variable is a string representing the file path (e.g., C:\Users\Me\HTML2PDF\Help\file.html), and you're trying to access .pdf as an attribute of a string, which doesn't exist. Instead, you need to create a new file path with the .pdf extension for the output file.
import glob
import pdfkit
import os

# Configure wkhtmltopdf path
config = pdfkit.configuration(wkhtmltopdf=r"C:\\Program Files\\wkhtmltopdf\\bin\\wkhtmltopdf.exe")

# Path to the HTML files
data = 'C:\\Users\\Me\\HTML2PDF\\Help\\*.html'

# Convert each HTML file to PDF
for name in glob.glob(data):
    # Create output PDF file path
    pdf_name = os.path.splitext(name)[0] + ".pdf"
    print(f"Converting {name} to {pdf_name}")
    # Convert HTML to PDF
    pdfkit.from_file(name, pdf_name, configuration=config)


Thanks! Was able to do all the html files!

Just as the error is telling you, name is a string.  But you're trying to access a property called pdf on that string:
pdfkit.from_file(name, name.pdf, configuration=config)

You probably meant to create a string, using name as a value therein.  Something like this:
pdfkit.from_file(name, f"{name}.pdf", configuration=config)


Hello, The error is too long to share here so here is the first part:Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\me\HTML2PDF\Converter.py", line 14, in 
pdfkit.from_file(name, f"{name}.pdf", configuration=config)
File "C:\Users\me\HTML2PDF.venv\Lib\site-packages\pdfkit\api.py", line 51, in from_file
return r.to_pdf(output_path)

File "C:\Users\me\HTML2PDF.venv\Lib\site-packages\pdfkit\pdfkit.py", line 201, in to_pdf
self.handle_error(exit_code, stderr)
File "C:\Users\me\HTML2PDF.venv\Lib\site-packages\pdfkit\pdfkit.py", line 155, in handle_error
raise IOError('wkhtmltopdf reported an error:\n' + stderr)
OSError: wkhtmltopdf reported an error:
Exit with code 1 due to network error: ProtocolUnknownError

@DenverDave: Is this error related to what's being addressed in the question/answer here?  Or is this a new problem to be debugged and investigated?  If the latter then you are encouraged to do that, and if you get stuck you can ask a new question and provide details about the problem in that question.  Comment threads are not the right tool for describing and solving new problems.

@DenverDave: Also, just searching the error message here finds: https://stackoverflow.com/q/73172817/328193 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/73599970/328193 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/32986470/328193, etc.

As what Denver is saying above, the first problem I see is that your output filename:
You should generate the output filename by simply replacing the .html extension with .pdf instead of name.pdf...
Consider adding an extra line within the for in loop:
output_name = os.path.splitext(name)[0] + '.pdf'


pdfkit.from_file(name, output_name, configuration=config)

As for the second error, it seems that wkhtmltopdf encountered a network-related issue, and I did some digging, this usually occurs if the HTML file references external resources (e.g. CSS, JS or images) and the referencing URL is invalid (broken CSS) or restricted... and wkhtmltopdf will throw an error like the one you mentioned above.
Or simply the provided URL is not recognizedby the module
Try adding:
options = {
'enable-local-file-access': None,  # Allows access to local files
'disable-smart-shrinking': None   # Optional but may resolve layout issues

}
and replacing:
pdfkit.from_file(name, output_name, configuration=config, options=options)

See if this fix your issue :)
